# Finding div id on the basis of its class name

Tags: jquery

I have to find div id on the basis of its class, if the div have class named searchItemSelected, then how to get its div id.

```
<div id="CheckinWithUser_4" class="CheckinWithUserRow1 searchItemSelected" onclick="" style="overflow: visible; height: 40px;">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All attributes of an element can be accessed through the .attr() method:

```
var id = $('.searchItemSelect').attr('id');
```

Comment: now how to handle if my html merkup is stored in a variable like var mymarkup = <div id="CheckinWithUser_4" class="CheckinWithUserRow1 searchItemSelected" onclick="" style="overflow: visible; height: 40px;">

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
var mymarkup = '<div id="CheckinWithUser_4" class="CheckinWithUserRow1 searchItemSelected" onclick="" style="overflow: visible; height: 40px;">';

if ($(mymarkup).hasClass("searchItemSelected")) 
{
    alert(this.id);
}
```