# Get id of div from its class name

Tags: javascript

How can I find an id based on its class just using javascript.  I know [this is easy with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965612/finding-div-id-on-the-basis-of-its-class-name) what is the solution.. using getElementsByTagName ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myClassName')[0].id
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.myClassName').id
```

Comment: It's cross browser when you check if one of the methods exists. And if not, fall back to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be find the element(s) with the given class name. There are currently some functions supported by modern browsers like `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelector` functions. but they are not cross browser solutions.

That is, `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by IE 6-8 and `querySelector` is not supported by IE6-7 & FF3
source: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Therefore if you are not supporting these browsers then you can use them else you would need a wrapper js function like one mentioned in [this blog post originally found on justswell.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130910163544/http://blog.justswell.org/clientside-getelementsbyclassname-cross-browser-implementation/).