# is there a way i can extract the id's from "getElementsByClassName('data')"?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to grab a list of ids from all elements that have a certain class.
in  a perfect world where everything was intuitive, it would look like this:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("data").id
```

this returns undefined and in the format of a NodeList.
I can manually use the console to search through the node list for the id(s).
i am by no means an expert so any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773550/get-id-of-div-from-its-class-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** is a **collection** of elements, and you can treat them like a simple array of elements.

As such, you can access them by index:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0].id);
```

```html
<div id="one" class="data">One</div>
<div id="two" class="data">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="data">Three</div>
```

Or loop over them:

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  console.log(list[i].id);
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="data">One</div>
<div id="two" class="data">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="data">Three</div>
```